# Zsh script cannot find screens

Tags: shell-script, zsh, gnu-screen

I have created a `zsh` script launching many screens in detached mode with particular names and running particular processes in them in order to automate some data analysis in high energy physics. However, I get the following error occasionally:

```
No screen session found.
```

I did not recognize a particular pattern for this `error` to be displayed and it seems to be taking place randomly, my aim is to launch this program many times with different `command-line arguments` and sometimes this error pops up in the second execution and sometimes in the third. In order to be able to perform the analysis, I need to send the particular command to the screens defined inside the `for` loops. The code is as follows:

```
#! /bin/zsh
### Script for running everything in screens ###
### System argument screen name suffix ###
echo You have the following screens running:
screen -ls
#echo Press any key to proceed. NOTE THAT YOUR OTHER SCREENS WILL GET KILLED!
#read
#pkill -15 -U arisevon screen ## We make sure that no screens are running for now
bkgarr=(TopJets BosonJets DiBoson TTbar)
sigarr=(NM1 NM2 NM3 Scenario4 Scenario6)
puarr=(50PU 140PU)
lumarr=(30 300 3000)
echo Please type 1 for 50PU samples and 2 for 140PU samples
read PU
if [[ $PU -ne 1 && $PU -ne 2 ]] ; then
    echo You have to enter 1 or 2
    return 1
fi

echo Please type 1 for 300fb-1 and 2 for 3000fb-1
read lum

if [[ $lum -ne 1 && $lum -ne 2 ]] ; then
    echo You have to enter 1 or 2
    return 1
fi

if [ $PU = 1 ]; then
    let "lum = $lum + 1"
    #echo $lum
fi

ex NEWrunReader.py  <<EOEX
  :43s/Lumi.*/Lumi=$lumarr[lum]/
  :x
EOEX

echo Compiling the reader file!!!
root -l << EOF
.L readerSummerStd.C+
EOF

echo Press any key to proceed or Ctrl+C to abort!
read 

for index in $bkgarr
do
    screen -dmS "${index}_${lumarr[lum]}_${1}" 
    #screen -S $index -p 0 -X stuff "$(typeset -p bkgarr)"$'\r'
    screen -S "${index}_${lumarr[lum]}_${1}" -p 0 -X stuff "./NEWrunReader.py SummerStd $puarr[PU]_$index $1 >& "${index}_${lumarr[lum]}_${1}".txt &"$'\r'
done

for sigind in $sigarr
do
    screen -dmS "${sigind}_${lumarr[lum]}_${1}" 
    #screen -S $sigind -p 0 -X stuff "$(typeset -p bkgarr)"$'\r'
    screen -S "${sigind}_${lumarr[lum]}_${1}" -p 0 -X stuff "./NEWrunReader.py SummerStd $puarr[PU]_$sigind $1 >& "${sigind}_${lumarr[lum]}_${1}".txt &"$'\r'
done
return 0
```

Comment: only guessing but it is possible you have race condition such that you `stuff` command is issued before the screen session has been initialised thus not visible. I'm also unsure about your `stuff` command because you provide some file name aftter `>&`. Even if it works, I think this still could be one line instead of 2 ...

Comment: @Bananguin I put some sleep stament inside the for loops and now it works fine.